# Compose a method name with a variable

Tags: perl

I have this code in a Mojolicious template:

```
my $lang = 'de'; # de, en, ...
% $col = 'internet' . '_' . $lang; 
%== markdown($rs->$col); # outputs correctly the content of the column internet_de
```

Is there a way to combine the lines 2 and 3 into something like:

```
%== markdown($rs->'internet' . '_' . $lang); # syntax error at template ..., near "->'internet'"
```

Comment: If there is, I wouldn't use it. That's pretty hard to read.

Comment: I'd go one step further and say there is no shorter way to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a ref-deref. This is analogue to the [baby cart](http://p3rl.org/perlsecret#Baby-cart).

```
$rs->${\"internet_$lang"}
$rs->${\('internet_' . $lang)}
```

Comment: Thanks, it's the answer to what I asked. Although in the context of the template I will now stick to the original two-liner for readability (as already pointed out above in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

Readabbility is quite an issue, so i would add a helper function to your Module:

```
sub access_it {
    my ($obj, $fun) = @_;
    return $obj->$fun
}
```

after that you should be able to use

```
%== markdown(access_it($rs,'internet' . '_' . $lang));
```

Comment: You don't need the prototype here.

Comment: I agree with @simbabque that the prototype is pointless here. But even if you're going to use a prototype, why have you marked `$fun` as optional? You're letting the user try to run `$obj->` - which seems wrong.

Answer (score -2):

I don't understand why you are striving to make your code even more concise. It is already hard to read, and golfing it further can only make it worse. In particular, you have a prime example of how comments can be used to make code less readable. And what are those `%` and `%==` doing there? Your code won't compile with those in place

You can use a scalar variable to provide the method name, but not a general expression

One improvement I would make is to use *interpolation* instead of string concatenation

```
my $lang   = 'de';
my $method = "internet_$lang";
markdown($rs->$method);
```

Comment: It is a [Mojolicious](http://mojolicious.org/perldoc/Mojo/Template) template, which explains the `%` and `%==` ;-)